# Google search automatically enters text

Tags: google-search

How can I prevent google.com searches from automatically entering my text. I have a Chrome extension that's supposed to allow me to use keyboard commands to navigate, but everything I type goes into the text box.

Comment: Maybe pressing tab or F6 might change focus away from the google search box and back to whatever it's supposed to be?

Comment: Typing a letter simply brings the focus back to the text box.

Comment: Maybe seek help with the extension author, F6 on my Chromium jumps from this comment text box up to the URL bar, and back to this box... **Shift+F6** cycles through the above 2 plus something else, maybe that? F10 opens up the main Menu...